# Getting IPython QtConsole and Notebook to work (Canopy installation) Python 3.X

Tags: python-3.x, installation, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am using Pyscripter right now but also want to use iPython because it can edit `Cython` code, which 
I want to practice since there is a debugger there.

I recently installed it with Canopy and the black prompt screen works but when I run the notebook it just shows a command prompt and does nothing and when I run the QtConsole (I am guessing it is that white screen with the [In] and [Out] stuff) I get an error (See picture).
[image]

**Update**: Installed QTConsole through Anaconda, QTConsole works but with Python 2.7, no notebook.

Comment: Enthought Canopy uses Python 2.7 only. This traceback would appear to be entirely within some (entirely different) Python 3.3 installation; also there's no sign in your traceback that you are using any part of Canopy. If you think there's a connection, please give more details about how you got to this point. If you have a PYTHONHOME environment variable set to your Python33 installation, that might account for the confusion.

Comment: @JonathanMarch I use Pyscripter for windows. Should I install Anaconda instead and try it out? I also can get Ipython from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy-stack but don't know if it would help

Comment: I don't know what it takes to get Anaconda to use Python 3.3. If you are content to use Python 2.7, Canopy Express includes both QtConsole and IPython Notebook out of the box. But you'd have to provide more information about what you are doing, no matter which distribution you are using.